# Exim sends system user mails rathen than logging them in /var/mail

Tags: logging, exim

I setuped an Exim4 server to send mail for my website hosted on the same server. I configured my server to have a mydomain.com hostname. Sites and mails for site are working fine.

The problem I have is that system messages are also sent by mail. Before I used to find my user system messages in /var/log/username now they are sent to username@mydomain.com.

How can I prevent this and keep logging message in /var/log for regular and root user ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your syslog (system logger whichever one you are using) and verify that the configuration is correct.

However, if you are talking about many application programs, you might have to dig in and find the appropriate settings that need changing in that application.

Comment: Thanks, any hint or keywold for configuration related to this problem ?